# XMLHttpRequest text send 404 error

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a text file on my server and I want to upload a text in it using XMLHttpRequest. It is downloaded successfully via GET method, but when I try to POST it I get 404 error.

```
var r1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
r1.open("GET", "db.txt", false);
r1.send();

var str = r1.responseText + "foo text";

var r2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
r2.open("POST", "db.txt", false);
r2.send(str);
```

Comment: you can't upload a file to your server via javascript

Comment: @Xone of course you can, just not directly like that.

Comment: Since the URL is the same, the server is broken. At worse it should be sending back a `405 Method Not Allowed` instead of a `404 Not Found`. Either way, the problem lies with the server and you need to set it up to process the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a direct upload as you're trying would be a security concern in most places and is generally not permitted... What you need to do is have a middle layer on your server to handle the request and write the file to disk safely.

You can easily upload a file using something like this:

```
var jsonBlob = new Blob([someJSON], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
var data = new FormData();

data.append("filename", "new.json");
data.append("json", jsonBlob);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var postURL = "http://example.com/post_target";
xhr.open("POST", postURL, true);
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    console.log(e.target.response);
  }
};
xhr.send(data);
```

Where `postURL` is an endpoint which can handle file uploads.

If you post what language(s) you have available on your server (PHP?) I can give some example code to handle the upload on the server's end.

Comment: Thanks @greg I was doing some testing on kissr.com a dropbox web hosting page. It does not support php, that is why I was wondering if uploading a file is possible with js. Without a handler for uploads it will not work.

Comment: @SercanAltundaş no problem.  If you're working with Dropbox you might want to have a look at their Datastore API https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/js

Comment: Also if this answers your question, could I trouble you to mark it accepted? (or clarify how I can improve it)